# my dialog box did not show up when I compile it using sdk 7.1,

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'd like to build a win32 application using sdk 7.1, I create the dialog box using Visual C++ 2012 resource editor, I copy resource.rc and resource.h to my folder and I write this simple main.cpp file:

```
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include "resource.h"

#define my_PROCESS_MESSAGE(hWnd, message, fn)   \
    case(message):  \
        return( \
            SetDlgMsgResult(hWnd, uMsg, \
                HANDLE_##message((hWnd), (wParam), (lParam), (fn)) ))   \

LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
BOOL Cls_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam);
void Cls_OnCommand(HWND hwnd, int id, HWND hwndCtl, UINT codeNotify);

int WINAPI _tWinMain(   HINSTANCE   hInstance,
                        HINSTANCE,
                        LPTSTR,
                        int         iCmdLine    )
{
    DialogBoxParam(     hInstance,
                        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_INJECTOR),
                        NULL,
                        (DLGPROC) DlgProc,
                        NULL
                        );

    return FALSE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(   HWND    hwnd,
                            UINT    uMsg,
                            WPARAM  wParam,
                            LPARAM  lParam  )
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        my_PROCESS_MESSAGE(hwnd, WM_INITDIALOG, Cls_OnInitDialog);
        my_PROCESS_MESSAGE(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, Cls_OnCommand);

    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


BOOL Cls_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return TRUE;
}

void Cls_OnCommand(HWND hwnd, int id, HWND hwndCtl, UINT codeNotify)
{
    switch(id)
    {
    case IDCANCEL:
        EndDialog(hwnd, id);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

then I use the following command line to compile my code, wich I found on this forum

```
cl main.cpp /link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS user32.lib
```

my problem is that my dialog box did not show up, and when I use procexp, to see what happen, I found that that my application is created then closed in the same time, and what make me wondering is that its working fine on Visual C++ 2012.

my sdk 7.1, installed correctly, I testing it against a basic window without any resource file

Comment: Check the return value of `DialogBoxParam`, and if it's `-1` check the return value of `GetLastError`. That may help to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "compile" the resource file with the resource compiler:

```
rc -r resource.rc
```

That will give you `resource.res`. You need to link that in when you create your executable:

```
cl main.cpp resource.res /link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS user32.lib
```

I haven't tested your code to see if it works then, but at least with the `.res` file linked in, it stands at lest some chance of working.

Comment: Jerry Coffin, thank you, you save my day, salute from Zirek

i face two other problems which i quickly solve, and i want to include the new solution in case any one have to face that problem again ..

end of line error ..., this error is a bug on the compiler, you just need to add a couple blank lines in the end of resource.h, ET voila, the 1st problem solved.

afxres.h not found, this is an mfc file, just replace it with windows.h in Resource.rc, then recompile again

that's it, and thank you again Jerry Coffin.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't your only problem, but, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Although the dialog box procedure is similar to a window procedure, it must **not** call the DefWindowProc function to process unwanted messages. Unwanted messages are processed internally by the dialog box window procedure.

[Emphasis added.]

Comment: i change that to: return FALSE, the probleme is that i need to compile the resource file 1st then proceed, tnx.